# TypeScript: How do I implement a multi method

Tags: typescript

I'am have:

```
interface Intfff
{
     csv: {
       (url: string);
       parsess(lol: string);      
   };
}

class Class implements Intfff
{
    csv(url: string) {

    }
}

var obj: Intfff = new Class();
obj.csv('sdfsdf');
obj.csv.parsess('sdf');
```

How do I implement a method  csv.parsess() ?
translator typeScript an error on Class: missing property 'parsess' from type ...

Help me understand

Answer (score 2):

Why not try this instead?

```
interface Intfff
{
    csv(url: string): Intfff;
    parsess(lol:string):string;
}

class TestClass implements Intfff
{
    csv(url: string) {  
        return this;
    }
    parsess(lol: string) {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

var obj: Intfff = new TestClass();
obj.csv('sdfsdf').parsess('sdf');
```

Comment: "obj.csv('sdfsdf').parsess('sdf');" is invalid expression. Should be:
obj.csv.parsess('sdf') // valid
obj.csv('str') // valid

Answer (score 2):

You can't fullfill that interface with a class method. You will have to define the function as type `any`, and add the missing member, before adding it to the object.

```
interface Intfff
{
    csv: {
        (url: string);
        parsess(lol: string);      
    };
}

class Test implements Intfff {
    public csv : { (url: string); parsess(lol: string); };

    constructor() {
        var csv : any = function (url: string) {
            // ...
        };
        csv.parsess = function (lol: string) {
            // ...
        };
        this.csv = csv;
    }
}
```